# Particle associated with material waves according to Wave particle duality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wave-particle-duality

What would be the particle associated with the material waves  (like water waves, sound waves) according to **Wave particle duality** and **de Broglie hypothesis**? Are those the medium particles (or molecules) themselves?
Edit:
for eg, photon is associated with electromagnetic wave. Just like this which particle is associated with material waves?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Mani I think your question is clear enough. Don't listen to bots.

Comment: It's hard to be sure what you're asking, but you might want to google the word "phonon".

Comment: I added an example to make the question clear.

Comment: @WillO Can every material wave be related with phonon?

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have a travelling particle, e.g. an electron.

With it is an associated [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) which is the solution to the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation).

The wave function is a mathematical object which contains all the information there is to know about the particle.

But the wave function is not a material wave as you state. For one, often wave functions are [Complex valued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) ($\in \mathbb{C}$), so they don't 'live in the Real world'.

Wave functions (often noted as $\psi$) are related to the probability of finding the particle in a part of space.

> Are those the medium particles (or molecules) themselves?

In the case of the electron, clearly 'yes', but not as a 'material wave'. The material waves idea is really an old and now obsolete interpretation of Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: @Gret what will we call the particle that is associated with a (say) water wave(ripples in water)? Will it be a phonon?

Comment: Firstly, remember that water waves are macroscopic and thus not subject to QM. Also they are Real valued ($\in \text{R}$) and not complex valued like electron 'waves'...